# What is this icon in Apache Netbeans?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, garbage-collection, ide

What is this icon below, third to right on the toolbar:

[image: screenshot]

There's nothing to compile or run.  Is it related to memory usage or garbage collection, perhaps?  Looks somewhat like the "memory toolbar":

https://ui.netbeans.org/docs/ui/ws/ws_spec-main_toolbar.html

Comment: It's showing "memory pressure" in the memory allocated by netbeans, netbeans runs in the JVM and the JVM consumes memory (as does netbeans).

Comment: okay, @ElliottFrisch and thanks.  somehow never noticed.

Answer (score 0):

from what I checked is measuring the memory capacity that is being consumed, I checked in the task manager.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).